# uWSGI rare gateway timeout

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

Good day everybody!

We have a simple web application (REST service) written using good old web.py and hosted on Nginx + uWSGI. The issue is that once in a zillion requests it fails fails with "504 Gateway Timeout" on the exact same handler, which does nothing but simple SQL SELECT query on an empty database (SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL), meaning query returns nothing. Here is uWSGI config:

```
uwsgi:
  enable-threads: 1
  threads: 1
  workers: 2
  master: 1
  socket: :8001
  plugin: python
  chown-socket: nginx:nginx
  pythonpath: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nailgun
  touch-reload: /var/lib/nailgun-uwsgi
  virtualenv: /usr
  module: nailgun.wsgi
  buffer-size: 49180
  listen: 4096
  pidfile: /tmp/nailgun.pid
  logto: /var/log/nailgun/app.log
  mule: 1
  lazy: true
  shared-pyimport: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nailgun/utils/mule.py
```

And here is the line from Python application log:

```
GET /api/nodes/ => generated 2 bytes in 10199124 msecs
```

uWSGI version is 2.0.3.

Can anyone please give a hint?

Comment: I'd suspect it runs out of database connection or other resources, or there is database connection failure, and then it sits out and waits forever for new connection until the worker terminated. Can you see if the timeout comes from Nginx or uWSGI (check response headers)

Comment: Looks like it's from uWSGI, because error appears first in its log. Also, it may possible have something to do with Docker, as application and Postgrsql are in different Docker containers.

Comment: Sharing the source code of the view timing out would give more hints what go wrong there. I suggest you add more logging to your application to narrow down the line where the failure happens.